# Check whether the string contains the given string or not

Tags: ruby

For ex: a.text has name "capybara" and I need to check whether the string has characters "ba" in it.

```
if a.text.contains?("ba")
  # do something
else
  # do something
end
```

Comment: what does this have to do with `Capybara`? is this in a capybara rspec feature test? Or just plain ruby?

Answer (score 6):

```
text = "capybara"
text.include?("ba")
=> true
```

so you could do:

```
if text.include?("ba")
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want more flexibility with regex, use [`match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-match) like:

```
if a.text.match(/ba/)
  # do something
end
```